# Create a stored procedure to get fill values in Date Dimension table in SSMS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, datetime

I'm getting errors on the semicolon after the select query(last 5th line), on the semicolon after End While(last 3rd line) and on the semicolon after End(last line). Can anybody explain why I'm getting these errors?

```
drop table if exists datedim;
create table datedim(
day_key int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
date datetime NULL,
Month int NULL,
MonthName varchar(9) NULL,
Year int NULL,
YearMonth char(6) NULL,
FirstDayOfMonth date NULL,
LastDayOfMonth date NULL,
);

Select * from datedim;

drop procedure if exists sp_datedim;
GO
create procedure sp_datedim (@p_start_date datetime, @p_end_date datetime)
AS
 Declare @StartDate datetime;
 Declare @EndDate datetime;
 Declare @RunDate datetime;

 Set @StartDate = @p_start_date;
 Set @EndDate = @p_end_date;
 Set @RunDate = @StartDate;

 WHILE @RunDate<=@EndDate 
 BEGIN
 INSERT into datedim(
 date,
 Month,
 MonthName,
 Year,
 YearMonth,
 FirstDayOfMonth,
 LastDayOfMonth
)
 SELECT
 DAY(@RunDate), 
 MONTH(@RunDate) month,
 DATENAME(MONTH, @RunDate),
 DATENAME(YEAR, @RunDate),
 MONTH(@RunDate),
 @RunDate-Day(@RunDate-1),
 EOMONTH(@RunDate),
 ;
 SET @RunDate = DATEADD(day,1,@RunDate);
 End WHILE;
 commit;
 END;
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags. And please post your actual errors.

Comment: If it's SQL Server: There is no `END WHILE` in T-SQL, only `END` (and only if there's also a corresponding `BEGIN`).

Comment: Start over - and THINK about your schema. You need a DATE column, not a DATETIME column for the date. That same thought applies to your procedure parameters. None of your columns should be nullable. And the day_key column serves no purpose. There are other improvements but that is a start.

Answer (score 1):

No need for loops.  You are always best using a set-based approach

**Example**

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2020-01-01'
Declare @Date2 date = '2021-12-31'


Select [Date]      = D
      ,[Month]     = datepart(MONTH,D)
      ,[MonthName] = datename(MONTH,D)
      ,[Year]      = datename(YEAR,D)
      ,[YearMonth] = replace(left(D,7),'-','')
      ,[BOM]       = datefromparts(year(D),month(D),1)
      ,[EOM]       = eomonth(D)
 From (
        Select Top (datediff(DAY,@Date1,@Date2)+1)
               D=dateadd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1)
         From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
      ) A
```

**Results**

```
Date        Month   MonthName   Year    YearMonth   BOM         EOM
2020-01-01  1       January     2020    202001      2020-01-01  2020-01-31
2020-01-02  1       January     2020    202001      2020-01-01  2020-01-31
2020-01-03  1       January     2020    202001      2020-01-01  2020-01-31
2020-01-04  1       January     2020    202001      2020-01-01  2020-01-31
2020-01-05  1       January     2020    202001      2020-01-01  2020-01-31
...
2021-12-28  12      December    2021    202112      2021-12-01  2021-12-31
2021-12-29  12      December    2021    202112      2021-12-01  2021-12-31
2021-12-30  12      December    2021    202112      2021-12-01  2021-12-31
2021-12-31  12      December    2021    202112      2021-12-01  2021-12-31
```